# I have a 2005 Ford Explorer that has a P0446 code that turnes the check engine light on,how do I repair this?

Tags: ford, repair, explorer, code, p0446

Check engine light is on, P0446 code comes up when diagnostic is done, vehicle is 2005 Ford Explorer, need to fix for emissions, need location on vehicle for me to repair

Comment: You are best to take it to a repair shop, too many things can set this code.

Answer (score 0):

"OBD-II Code P0446 is defined as a Evaporative System Vent Control Circuit Malfunction"

From this [website](https://repairpal.com/obd-ii-code-p0446).

Common Problems That Trigger the P0446 Code

```
Missing fuel cap
Defective Evaporative Vent Valve
Defective or damaged fuel cap
Distorted, damaged or cracked Fuel Tank Filler Neck
Torn or punctured Evaporative system hose(s)
Defective Fuel Tank Sending Unit gasket or seal
Split or damaged Carbon Canister
Defective or damaged fuel tank
```

Now you know what the code is you can research ways to diagnose and address the issue.

[FULL LIST OF OBD II CODES 1996 AND NEWER](https://www.freeautomechanic.com/diagnostictroublecodes6.html)

Comment: I'm not going to upvote this because it doesn't really tell anything beyond what can be found in a web search @AlaskaMan. Which of the common problems is most common on the make and model of the car, or any car? For instance would it make sense to check the fuel cap before tearing into the mechanicals?

Comment: It was a short question with not enough info and there is no way to answer it definitively. It provides more info than the OP led us to believe he knew. It gave him a list of possibilities, he can choose in what order he would  like to investigate the things on the list.  "*For instance would it make sense to check the fuel cap before tearing into the mechanical's*?" YES, Start with the easiest and cheapest  would be the common a sense way to start. I have common sense, i  believe other should.   Perhaps it pointed him the right direction, that is all i care about.  I am not here for votes.